# Restarting windows service from website

Tags: windows, vb.net, security, iis, service

I've a website that puts info into a mySQL database and a windows service (written in VB.Net) that polls the db and actions what's in there.
However, occasionally it stalls and rather than having to RDP into the server, I want superusers to click on a button to restart the service.
I can get the button to say, do a directory listing of c:\ output to a test file so the whole 'getting a command to execute on a remote server' issue works. However, I can't restart services.
I assume this is a security thing (although it has full rights to c:\ I thought I'd sussed that already).
The website runs under the normal IUSR_user so am I doing something really stupid or can someone explain how to get the service to be restarted ?

Many thanks
Adrian

Comment: Related question: http://serverfault.com/questions/7979/starting-and-stopping-services

Comment: I take it you've ruled out fixing the service?

Comment: it's complicated !!! basically it talks to routers which sometimes timeout or give back garbage.And I use threading :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think a significantly bigger problem is that you have a service that's stalling. Do you have any logs or errors that the service outputs to that you could use to diagnose *why* it's stalling?

Answer (score 0):

I'd write a service that restarts selected services and call that from my website, just for fun!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [you need to give the user permissions](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325349) on the specific service. The simplest way to do this (in my view) is to use `subinacl.exe` from the [Windows Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/Downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=9d467a69-57ff-4ae7-96ee-b18c4790cffd).

```
subinacl.exe /service MySQL /Grant=IUSR_user
```

I'm would be very careful when doing this on a public-facing web server. Have both authentication and rate limiting on the restarting code.

Comment: It's not public facing so no issues there. Installed it, ran the command as you showed but alas, no joy. Shows no error message, just doesn't do anything :-(

Answer (score 0):

Use the ServiceController class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx

This should allow you to connect to the named service and stop/start it.

EDIT:
In addition, you probably need to have your web app impersonate a user with rights to restart the service. This can be accomplished via an identity impersonate in the web.config, or running the web app in a configured application pool in IIS.  Keep in mind that the web app will have to run on the same box as the service is running on.

Comment: do you have any web.config samples showing how to impersonate someone ?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. Create an IIS application pool with the identity of the domain user you want your app to run as. Add your application to this pool

Then in the web.config add:

    <system.web>
<identity impersonate="true" />
</system.web>

Your web app will then run as the domain user that you specified in its application pool